# Cannot Open Layout Files in Android-Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have changed the project structure asno suggested in [Can't read ... AndroidManifest.xml - while attempting Android Notepad Tutorial - Exercise 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025152/cant-read-androidmanifest-xml-while-attempting-android-notepad-tutorial) and restarted android studio yet the problem persists.
I have stopped using eclipse because R file is being generated inconsistently.

http://i1273.photobucket.com/albums/y410/sreeram_b93/what_wrong_zps57e75df9.png

EDIT: Earlier problem about opening  android Manifest file has been solved by updating to 130.7 build.

**New Problem: Cannot open or edit Layout Files Version: SDK Tools:22 SDK Platform:21 Android-studio Build:130.7**

Comment: Are you still able to run the project? Are you importing the project correctly? For importing do `File -> New Android Project`. In the Contents Tab in `New Android Project`, select `Create project from existing source` and choose the Build Target. Is this the way you are doing?

Comment: Thank You, That problem has been solved by updating android-studio. 
Check out the new Problem

Comment: For the record, I'm having this same problem with a project I made entirely in Android Studio. I'm eagerly awaiting an answer to this. I also experienced an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and my `R` is no longer generating. May or may not be related to this bug but happened all at the same time for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had placed a new folder in my `res` folder with original non-resized images of my icons and resources in case I want to edit them later. This broke Android Studio in several places. As soon as I moved that folder elsewhere, everything returned to normal.

Comment: I did the same thing and I have also notified Tor Norbye on google plus android studio community.He was astonished but noted it as a bug.